# How to disable drag/drop functionality in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Chrome browser has this weird functionality that when I drag a div, or image, it drags that item. For example, if you go to http://www.google.com you'll be able to drag that google image.

The thing is, it's messing with my javascript events. Is there a way, in javascript to disable this functionality for the chrome/safari browser?

Comment: Does this help -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704564/disable-drag-and-drop-on-html-elements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling

```
event.preventDefault();
```

in your event handler should disable that.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault)

Answer (score 12):

The other answers suggesting `.preventDefault()` do not work for me in Chrome (v26). Had to set `draggable='false'` HTML5 attribute on the image. FWIW I'm using the threedubmedia drag jQuery plugin (actually the nifty newer [jdragdrop](https://github.com/haberman/jdragdrop) reimplementation).

Comment: This makes [hammer](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/) drag and swipe events work correctly

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I needed to create my own drag and drop functionality. I was using mousedown, mouseup, and mousemove events. I solved it by adding `event.preventDefault();` as the first line in my mousedown event handler.