# How to disable an element in HTML page but be able to drag it with jQuery draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, draggable

I make an element on a page with mouse click somewhere on the page by inputting something like this to the document:

```
$("#sheet").append('<input class="elements" id="Button12" type="button" value="button" />');
```

But I don't want to be clickable for a while,so I can disable it:

```
$(".elements").prop('disabled', true);
```

**But the problem is,** I want this element to be draggable so I can move it on the page, I tried this but doesn't work:

```
$('.elements').draggable
({
    containment: "#frame",
    grid: [5,5]
})
```

**How can an element be draggable while it is unclickable?**

Comment: That's not your actual `append()` string, is it? It's missing some quotes on the string.

Comment: yes sorry, missed while simplifying it :)

Comment: Have you call `.draggable()` method after appending your button?

Comment: Is there any error in your JS console on firebug or chrome inspector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually better with form elements when animating, or dragging to wrap in another container. In this case insert another element positioned absolute and higher z-index that fills the wrapping container, and covers the disabled input since mouse events won't register on the disabled element. By covering the input, mousedown for drag will occur on the inner span.

```
var input='<span class="element_wrap"><span class="element_wrap_inner"></span>';
    input+='<input class="elements" id="Button12" type="button" value="button" disabled+"disabled" /></span>';

$("#sheet").append(input);

$('.elements_wrap').draggable({
    containment: "#frame",
    grid: [5,5]
});
```

Apply appropriate css. When enabling the input, hide or remove the inner span

DEMO:  Using click on a  disabled checkbox for simplicity   http://jsfiddle.net/KtP5K/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".elements").children().prop('disabled', true);
```

should be

```
$(".elements").prop('disabled', true);
```

because `.elements` is button itself.

and

```
$("#sheet").append(<input class="elements" id="Button12" type="button" value="button" />);
```

should be

```
$("#sheet").append('<input class="elements" id="Button12" type="button" value="button" />'); // missed quote
```

and I think your `draggable` code should be **(and must be after `append()` statement)**

```
$('.elements').draggable
({
    containment: "#frame",
    grid: [5,5]
})
```

Comment: + 1 bruv, for OP: if I can suggest to OP in case of already disabled element use `e.preventDeafult` or this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704564/disable-drag-and-drop-on-html-elements

Comment: thank you, but still doesn't work. seems the problem is: if it is disabled can't be draggable.

Comment: @all, sorry that children() stuff and quote are just missed when I was removing unnecessary things.

Comment: @Tooraj: then I have two problems, first I don't want to be clickable, it is a form designer, and second it isn't draggable while I click on it :)