# How can i make it so an image cant be dragged?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable Drag and Drop on HTML elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704564/disable-drag-and-drop-on-html-elements)

I was wondering if there is a way to make certain images so they cant be drag? I would think there would be a css attribute however i cant find anything.

This is the site im working on: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqzbG.png
My goal is to make it so the logo cant be dragged.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704564/disable-drag-and-drop-on-html-elements

Comment: negative votes should be commented, I think ..

Answer (score -2):

this is how to enable and disable drag effect

```
$("#imageid").draggable('disable'); //disable
$("#imageid").draggable();  //enable
```

Now it really depends on you were to do this.

Comment: The question doesn't mention jQuery and isn't tagged with jQuery.

Comment: man its javascript, and he can use jquery to solve his problem. for me jquery and javascript are almost one. anyway good luck