# Javascript prevent drag selection of multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to prevent the user from dragging and selecting multiple elements text?

Currently I'm using the following CSS on elements that I want the user to be able to select:

```
-moz-user-select: text;
-khtml-user-select: text;
-webkit-user-select: text;
-ms-user-select: text;
user-select: text;
```

And I've set this in the body:

```
-moz-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

The goal here is to only let the user to select one elements text at a time.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704564/disable-drag-and-drop-on-html-elements

Answer (score 0):

CSS on elements that the user should to be able to select. select one element at time

```
-moz-user-select: element;
-khtml-user-select: element;
-webkit-user-select: element;
-ms-user-select: element;
 user-select: element;
```

Comment: Please add some explanations.