# Prevent Drag and Drop on one table inside Div: Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I have two tables in a below Div. Out of that, I would like to prevent drag and drop functionality on one table and other should have drag and drop functionality.

I was able to successfully stop drag and drop on Div level (please see working code, I found this code from [Disable Drag and Drop on HTML elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704564/disable-drag-and-drop-on-html-elements)) 
However when I tried to assign similar code to specific table, it does not work and I am able to perform drag and drop on those tables.

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
    <table id="s_1" summary="Table 1" > </table> 
    <table id="s_2" summary="Table 2" > </table> 
</div>
```

Java Script:

Working:

```
/* drag and drop    */

            $('.test').bind("dragover", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });

            $('.test').bind("drop", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
```

Not Working:

```
$('.test table').each(function(){ 

    console.log($(this).attr("summary"));  
    if ($(this).attr("summary") == "Table 2") {

        $(this).bind("dragover", function(e) {
                console.log($(this).attr("summary"));  
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
        });

        $(this).bind("drop", function(e){
                console.log($(this).attr("summary"));  
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cancel the `mousedown` event:

```
$(this).on('mousedown', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

But you can do it inside HTML if you want:

```
<table id="s_2" summary="Table 2" onmousedown="return false"> </table>
```

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki If you want to listen for that event and cancel it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This way you get to listen to that event too.

```
    $(this).on('mousedown', function(e) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

More info on stopPropogation [here](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: Thank you guys.. but with that also it is preventing drag and drop from entire DIV and not specific to have table.