# Drag div issue with ghost images

Tags: javascript, html, css

everyone.
I want to disable user ability to drag with JavaScript. It's a moment when a mouse turning to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q76wA.png)  if u hold your primary mouse pressed long enough and u see that ghost image of an element.

I have grid 10x10 elements [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbeJI.png) and event listener for parent container.

```
let parent = document.getElementsByClassName("bottomPart")[0];
parent.addEventListener("mousemove", moveFunction);
```

After dragging mouse elements should change his color

```
function moveFunction(target){
    if(target.buttons == 1){
    let bulb = document.getElementById(target.toElement.id);
        if(bulb!=null){
            bulb.style.background = `rgb(${color.r},${color.g},${color.b})`;
        }
    }
}
```

For the first time it's all [good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCCf8.png).
But then the issue occurs the mouse on drag turns into [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q76wA.png). And i can't change color anymore.

Comment: please add more information, some code as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Drag and Drop on HTML elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704564/disable-drag-and-drop-on-html-elements)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can't find the answer because didn't know what should I am searching.